# How to setup a Linux laptop as a MIDI device?

Tags: linux, audio, recording, midi

Which external MIDI interface will work on Linux to use a software sequencer with an external expander?

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understand you right, every single one, I mean, because that's what a MIDI interface is supposed to do ; Here I have this setup :

- Novation X-Station USB audio
- Korg trinity rack (plugged to the XStation via MIDI cable out=>in)
- Mandriva GNU/Linux (regular kernel) running [qtractor](http://qtractor.sourceforge.net/)

This already works as is. But it gets better: inside the XStation, there is a built-in synth, a "Novation KStation" and it is controlled by qtractor as well.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a MIDI interface on which I could plug a MIDI expander on one side (MIDI DIN) and a laptop on the other side (USB, ...) and that works fine with Linux. So I can use, say, qtractor with an external synth which has only DIN connectors.

Comment: Yes, you can indeed.